# Response code: 418 'I'm a teapot' in jmeter

Tags: json, https, jmeter, postman, web-api-testing

I've been trying to test the API of restful-booker in Jmeter. But whenever I try to create a booking or Get a Booking by id I'm getting the HTTP response:418 'I'm a teapot'.If I try to access the URL in the browser it says the same. But when I run this in postman it does not give any kind of error. Also, it shows the correct response in Code Beautify. Really frustrating. Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: "When I run this in postman", what kind of request do you make in postman? GET? POST? Also, you say that it does not give any kind of error (when run in postman), does this mean it succeeded?

Comment: Create booking - post, get a booking by id i- get. and they succeeded .gives the expected response.

Comment: Could you please check the request (body and headers) in both Postman and JMeter? It looks like there is something missing in the content of the request. You may use a tool like [JSON Diff](http://www.jsondiff.com) to compare the JSON. Hope this will help you to identify the issue with JMeter script. Let me know how it goes with you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I double-checked and found I didn't add the 'accept' header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here: you forgot add `accept: application/json` in jmeter, postman automatically adds this setting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I did forget to add it. it's running perfectly now. thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you're capable of successfully executing the request in postman (or whatever else tool) and not able to do it with JMeter most probably you're sending a different request.

Check out literally everything: URL, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), body, etc. - all matters.

There are 2 approaches:

1. Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) to capture the requests from postman and JMeter and compare them for differences
2. Or [just record the request from Postman using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling), JMeter will capture the request and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)